# import LocomotiveScroll from 'locomotive-scroll'; isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, locomotive-scroll

apparently LocomotiveScroll isn't imported, so I can't use smooth scroll:
'''import LocomotiveScroll from 'locomotive-scroll';'''

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue while using typescript. I was able to resolve it by installing the locomotive type definitions after I installed locomotive itself.

```
npm install locomotive-scroll
npm i --save-dev @types/locomotive-scroll
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to install locomotive scroll

try

```
npm install locomotive-scroll
```

and then on you js file

```
import LocomotiveScroll from "locomotive-scroll";

   let options = {
        el: currentScrollContainer,
        smooth: true,
        getSpeed: true,
        getDirection: true,
    };
    scroll = new LocomotiveScroll(options);
```